# How do I change the order of my contacts on the frequent contact toolbar?

Tags: contacts, motorola-droid-4

I have a Droid 4. How do I change the order of my contacts on the frequent contact toolbar on my main screen?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the order it determined by the frequency you call or receives calls from these contacts (maybe SMS messages are also counted). There is IIRC no manual way to fix the order.